# How to calculate the probability od success of bernouli trials when the probability is itself randomly distributed?

Tags: probability

Consider Bernoulli trials where p, the probability of success, itself may
be random. Suppose p is distributed uniformly over $(0, 1)$. That is, we
first choose a random number from $(0, 1)$ and then using this as p (the
probability of success) now perform a sequence of n Bernoulli
trials.

Let X denote the number of successes. Using the identity $$ \int_{0}^{1} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\,dp = \frac{k!(n−k)!}{(n+1)!}$$
(which comes from our knowledge of beta-density),

show that

$$ P[X=k] = \int_0^1 P[X=k|p]f(p)dp=\frac{1}{n+1} , k=0,1,2,...n $$
Also show that the probability that the $(r+1)st $ is a success given that there were k successes in the first r trials is $\frac{k+1}{r+2}$

So here is my attempt at the solution,

Since p is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 we can say that $f(p)=1, 0<p<1$
Thus$$ P[X=k] = \int_0^1 P[X=k|p]f(p)dp=\int_0^1 P[X=k|p]dp$$
$$ =\int_{0}^{1} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\,dp = \frac{k!(n−k)!}{(n+1)!}$$
What is the wrong with my solution?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the binomial coefficient in the probability formula. In other words:

$$P[X=k|p]=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me with the second part? I know k successes at r+1 trials is $\frac{1}{r+2}$. But how do I ensure that this is true for r+1 st success?

Comment: Never mind I got it! Essentially I am asking how to distribute k successes among the r trials and then the r+1 st is  a success. So the inner intergral becomes $\binom{r}{k}p^{k+1}(1-p)^{r+1-(k+1)}$

Comment: No I am not getting it. We are getting $\frac{k+1}{(r+1)(r+2)}$ Can you help me where I am getting it wrong? Answer is $\frac{k+1}{(r+2)}$